# Slow snap to grid in macOS

Tags: macos, icons, desktop-icons

I just got a new Macbook Pro, and in my 2012 Macbook Pro if I move an icon on the desktop it moves slowly to snap to the underlying grid. This is very aesthetically pleasing. My new laptop moves icons instantaneously. How can I change it to match my old laptop?

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Superuser! An issue like this can be a bit hard for people to visualize. You might consider editing your answer by uploading a couple of videos/gifs illustrating the current and desired behaviour respectively.
Also, in my opinion as a Mac user, I doubt a feature exists that allows you to toggle the speed at which items snap to the grid, unfortunately :(

Comment: I currently have the slow movement on my 2012 Macbook Pro running macOS Mojave, but I have no idea how I enabled it in the first place. I've had it for a long time...